# Multitable query mysql

Tags: php, mysql

[image]

I am in process of creating multi variable & multi table search query for Job Portal. Got some success in creating following long query which gives results as required. I need to replace above highlighted red circle delimited values (which i created using GROUP_CONCAT function in following query) with follwoing table description values.

Note:- Delimited values are not in database field. I'am creating these using following query.

My other table structure is as follows:

```
+---------------------------------------------+
   ID                     Description
+---------------------------------------------+
    1                     Delhi
    2                     Mumbai
    3                     Chennai
    4                     Kolkata
+----------------------------------------------+
```

Please help me to guide a way forward for one, rest i'll do it myself.

```
Select 
    a.user_id, g.username, a.mobile_no, a.location, a.DOB, a.current_CTC,     
    a.expected_CTC, a.work_exp, a.job_type, a.designation, a.Company_name,  
    a.keyskills, a.profile_headline, a.resume_path, a.Notice_period, 
    DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),Max(b.Login_date_time)) as Last_Login_days, 
    Max(b.Login_date_time) as Last_Available_on_site,

   (Select GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.Education_ID ORDER BY c.Education_ID 
   SEPARATOR ', ') user_education from user_education c where a.user_id = 
   c.User_ID) as Education_ID,

   (Select GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT d.FA_ID ORDER BY d.FA_ID SEPARATOR ', ') FA 
   from user_fa d where a.user_id = d.User_ID) as FA_ID,

   (Select GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT e.Industry_ID ORDER BY e.Industry_ID   
   SEPARATOR ', ') Industry_ID from user_industry e where a.user_id = 
   e.User_ID) as Industry_ID,

   (Select GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT f.Location_ID ORDER BY f.Location_ID 
   SEPARATOR ', ') Location_ID from user_preferred_locations f where 
   a.user_id = f.User_ID) as Preferred_Location_ID

   from user_details a

   left join login_history b on a.user_id = b.user_id 
   left join users g on a.user_id = g.id
   left join user_education c on a.user_id = c.User_ID
   left join user_fa d on a.user_id = d.User_ID
   left join user_industry e on a.user_id = e.User_ID
   left join user_preferred_locations f on a.user_id = f.User_ID
   INNER JOIN locations h ON FIND_IN_SET(h.location_id, f.Location_ID)
   WHERE MATCH(keyskills) AGAINST('MIS, Analysis' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
   And YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(DOB)>= 18 And YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(DOB)<= 45
   And work_exp >= 2 And work_exp <= 15 
   And a.current_CTC>=102 And a.current_CTC<=115 
   And a.industry IN (10001,10002,10004)
   And a.functional_area IN(1001,1002,1003) 
   And a.location_preferred IN (1,2,3,4,6,7)
   And Education_ID IN (1,5,7,8)
   And a.job_type Like '%FTP%' 
   And Notice_period >= 15
   And b.Login_date_time>=0
   And a.mobile_no is not null
   And resume_path is not null
   group by a.user_id
```

Comment: it would highly appreciable if you help to shorten this query :-)

Comment: Just to inform, i am creating this query to provide results from database against saved search (saved by Employer to get results by one click). And of course i need not to tell post reading that this belongs to Job portal. :-)

Comment: Generally speaking, it's a *bad idea* to concatenate data at the database layer; the data access layer really ought to be furnished with discrete entities for it to handle however it may need (okay, yes, it can parse and split delimited strings—but what's the point in doing that, especially when erroneous escaping can lead to literal delimiter characters being mistreated, or worse?).

Comment: `Please help me to guide a way forward for one, rest i'll do it myself.` . Please tell a little more what result you want and where are you stuck

Comment: just added image of search result. Highlighted red circle data i'am populating from above query. I need to convert red circle values to description i shared above. All circles has to be linked with different tables to get their descriptions. Just wanted to have some guidance for one.

Comment: @eggyal - This is the best i could have come up. In case you can help to guide some better way/approach to solve this matter. Would be really grateful to you.

Comment: Note : When giving alias to a table use `Proper/descriptive` alias rather than a,b,c,d,e . For example for user_education it should be `ue` . Do you do this SQL coding in such big project? You surely will get messed up on this track many times!

Comment: Thanks for highlighting this objection. Will take care while final version. this one is under testing for now. :-)